# How to deal with Commas in CSV using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, csv, asp.net-mvc-4, export-to-csv

I am having some data which is facing issue while exporting to csv if the data contains "," with in it.

Hereis the code:

```
  CSVData.push('"' + item.OrgId+ '","' + item.Name + '","' + item.OrgDescriptionString + '","' + itam.OrgDetailsString + '","' + item.Active+ '"');
```

if orgDetaisl string contains "," with in it, the data is getting overlapped and moving to next column.

How to escape "," .I tried using double quotes """ but not sure how can i achieve.

```
CSVData.push('"' + item.OrgId+ '","' + item.Name + '","\""' + item.OrgDescriptionString + '"\"","\""' + item.OrgDetailsString + ' \"","' + item.Active+ '"');
```

Please correct the string and help me to escape "," with in the data.

Comment: When you create the CSV use a different column separator

Comment: @Gerard! Then it is not a CSV

Answer (score 13):

The proper way to escape separators inside fields is to enclose the fields in double quotes:

```
Id,Description
123,"Monitor, Samsung"
```

But then quotes inside the field have to be escaped with another quote:

```
Id,Description
123,"Monitor 24"", Samsung"
```

Of course, a different delimiter like `;` could be used, but then you'd still have to check if those appear in the data.

Comment: What you suggested didn't work. Please provide fiddler for it

Answer (score 12):

I tried to with the below code and it worked for me

```
item.OrgDescriptionString.replace(/\"/g, "\"\"");
```

I tried to escape single quotes in the string and it worked.

Answer (score 6):

This is how I have achieved the reported functionality.

**In brief:** Requirement was to fetch the comma-separated string as it is in the CSV Export.

Assuming that we have a comma-separated string which needs to be exported in the CSV as it is.

**For example** String value which comes from the data source as:

'StackOverflow', 'Awesome! work by StackOverflow team, cheers to them.'

**Solution:**

```
['stackoverflow', 'Awesome! work by stackoverflow team, cheers to them.'].map(string => string === null ? '' : `\"${string}\"`);
```

**Explanation:** So if we quote the comma-separated values and try exporting than the CSV will not consider the comma(,) as a field separator and due to which in CSV export it won't split into multiple columns with respect to numbers of available commas. And the content will appear in the same column.

Ref wiki link: [Comma-separated_values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values)

Hope this helps. Cheers!!

Comment: if you have a value with quotes already this solution wont work. It works fine for other scenarios.

Answer (score 2):

Use double-quotes enclosed string and escape double-quotes in string:

```
csvData.push( "\\"" + strData.replace( /\\"/g , "\\"\\"" ) + "\\"" )
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the probable solution could be to read the file and then replace the read data with ""

Something like this:

```
readData = readData.replace(/,/g, "");
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar situation, here is the string that needs to be printed in the csv file:

> '"P1", "Graded Reader": "The Three", Bears 15 Jun 2023'

then i solved it by use Template literals (Template strings):

```
const exampleString = '"P1", "Graded Reader": "The Three", Bears';
const time = '15 Jun 2023';

const finalString = `"${exampleString?.replace(/"/g, '""')}" ${time}`;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple, suppose an address variable containing the commas,, then you should enclosed it in double quotes.

```
data.push('"'+address+'"');
```

or

in my case it is working fine!